# subsequent command execution on successful catch of an exception at a higher level

Tags: c#, exception

For an app I am working on, one of my teammates has been working on a generic error handler that performs some reporting to our team when one of our systems gets into an exceptional state, at a relatively high level.

However, a few weeks back, I wrote some code at a low level (specifically, database access) that provides some notification.  With the advent of this team member's high-level code, the rest of the team feels we can safely remove my try/catch system.

One catch: there's a `IsSuccessful` flag on the data structure returned from this particular repository method.  When an exception occurs, this flag is kept false (on successful data acquisition, the flag is set to true.)

So, for the time being, my code looks like this:

```
public FooResult Foo()
{
  FooResult result = new FooResult { IsSuccessful = false };
  SqlParameter[] args = new []
  {
    // Some args, immaterial to the situation.
  }

  try
  {
    DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(_connection, CommandType.Text, query, args);
    result = new FooResult
             {
               IsSuccessful = true,
               // ...Other fields are set...
             };
  }
  catch
  {
    result.IsSuccessful = false;
    throw;   // Per request
  }

  return result;
}
```

Which leads to my **Question**: upon throwing an exception and it being handled at a higher level, what happens after that?  Does my code bubble back down to where it left off, or does execution resume elsewhere?  When things go wrong and are cleaned up at a different level, where does the code keep going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throwing an exception forces a `stack unwinding`, this means, that the current execution stack will be abandoned and eventually you end up, where there is a `catch()`.
This means, if you catch an `exception` in a calling method, you will end up in ist `catch()`-handler and you will not return to where the exception occured in the callee. So if you have a return-statement, this will never be reached!

[Here](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/2346-call-stack-call-site-and-stack-unwinding.aspx) is a nice short article on this.

Answer (score 1):

The `FooResult` object you're creating inside of `Foo()` will never be returned if you throw an exception in there.

Exceptions break the normal control flow of your code and bubble on up until either someone catches the exception or the program halts altogether.

It is possible that the higher level may catch an exception and retry, but that's outside of your method's hands.

Comment: Both you and bash.d gave great answers, but I accepted his because he gave just a tad more information.  Thank you very much for taking the time to answer, though!